# Node js open ssl(not secured) https services issue in android app

Tags: android, node.js, https

I integrated node js open SSL(not secured) https services In my android app. but it is not working. if I integrated in web app first time it is showing an error message that "Your connection is not secured" then in advance setting i am allowing then it is working but in android app it throwing same exception. how to solve this issue.

Comment: Which device you're using ? Please paste the error log/stacktrace

Comment: com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: i am testing oppo android mobile

Answer (score 0):

1. Add certification file in your assets folder.
2. Run the following code to make android trust this certification.

Call below **trustCert()** method like this -

`httpsURLConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(trustCert().getSocketFactory());`

```
     private SSLContext trustCert()throws CertificateException,

        IOException,KeyStoreException,

    NoSuchAlgorithmException,KeyManagementException{

    AssetManager assetManager=getAssets();

    CertificateFactory cf=CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

    Certificate ca=cf.generateCertificate(assetManager.open("fileName.crt"));

    // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs

    String keyStoreType=KeyStore.getDefaultType();
    KeyStore keyStore=KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
    keyStore.load(null,null);
    keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca",ca);

     // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore

    String tmfAlgorithm=TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
    TrustManagerFactory tmf=TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
    tmf.init(keyStore);

     // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
    SSLContext context=SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null,tmf.getTrustManagers(),null);
    return context;
    }
```

Comment: Please upvote this and happy to help you :)@Rajesh Yadav